# For $ n\to\infty $, does $A_{n\to\infty}$ contain all possible infinite length sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, infinity

I don't claim to have chosen the right words and notations in the question. I'm trying to understand the concepts.

Let, the set $A_n$ is given.

The set of $A_n$, is the set of all possible sequences, which is consist of elements $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$,  digit's lentgh equal to $n.$

Example:

$A_3:=\left\{(0,0,0);(0,0,1);(0,0,2);(0,1,0);(0,1,1);\\(0,1,2);(0,2,0);(0,2,1);(0,2,2),(1,0,0);(1,0,1);\\(1,0,2);(1,1,0);(1,1,1);(1,1,2);(1,2,0);(1,2,1);\\(1,2,2);(2,0,0);(2,0,1);(2,0,2);(2,1,0);(2,1,1);\\(2,1,2);(2,2,0);(2,2,1);(2,2,2)\right\}$

Now, if we include $n\to\infty$, (infinite lentgh of sequences) can we say:

> *Question-1*
>
> For $n\to\infty$, the set of $A_{n\to\infty}$ contains all possible infinite length sequences. Is this claim correct?
>
> *Question-2*
>
> For $n\to\infty$, since the set of $A_{n\to\infty}$ contains all possible infinite length sequences, this imply the cardinality of set of $A_{n\to\infty}$ is equal to $2 ^ {\aleph_0}.$ Is this claim correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is $A_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila infinite lentgh of sequences.

Comment: Then what does the $\to$ signify here?

Comment: Also, your sets have sequences as elements, not sets. (1) Sets are denoted by $\{...\}$ and (2) $\{2,2,2,2,0\}=\{0,0,0,2\}=\{0,2\}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  You are right.I think I mixed the concepts again :(

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean $n\to\infty$, $n$ is not a finite number. Or $n$ is continuous.

Comment: Okay, but there are *many* kind of infinite lengths (or: transfinite), the $n\to\infty$ hints that you're thinking about somehow "a limit" going on (especially since you write $2^{\aleph_0}$ there). And that's difficult to understand exactly what you mean there. The $n\to\infty$ notations is hinting the reader (in this case, me) that there is more implicit assumptions here, and to be able and fully answer your question, those needs to be explicit.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I can't express my question in a clear way.  Now I don't know how to do it.  Thank you for your comments.  What section should I read in set theory that is related to this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed elsewhere on this page, there's some inherent ambiguity about the use of $\infty$. It is sometimes clear from context, but it is sometimes not.

You could say that $\infty$ here represents $\Bbb N$, or $\omega$ as it is usually denoted in set theory, as the smallest infinite ordinal. And that would indeed make sense. And indeed, in that case, $A_\omega$ would be all the functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1,2\}$, and yes that would be a set of size $2^{\aleph_0}$.

But you could also think about somehow the limit of the finite sequences, and these would be the sequences which are finite, or if you prefer to think about infinite sequences, then those would be the sequences which are eventually zero, or eventually constant. In this case, the collection of sequences is countable. We can see that by first enumerating the prime numbers, $p_0,p_1,\dots$ and then mapping the [eventually $0$] sequence $a_n$ to $\prod p_i^{a_i}$, as only finitely many $a_i$'s are non-zero, this would be a well-defined natural number and it is easy to verify this is an injection (not a bijection, since $a_i$ is at most $2$).

Answer (score 2):

When you write $A_{n\to\infty}$ I believe that you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$, that is the union of all possible $A_k$.

---

The claim in question 1 is incorrect, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$ only contains finite sequences. It contains an infinite amount of them, with ever growing sizes, but each individual sequence is finite.

Similarly the claim in question 2 is incorrect, based on the false assumption in question 2. The cardinality of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$ is still $\aleph_0$. It's a bit trickier to come up with a direct mapping, but here's a hint: a countable combination of countable objects is still countable because bijections between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$ exist.

Comment: $n\to\infty$ I mean the lentgh of  sequences is continuous.

Comment: @Elementary The length of sequences can't be continuous, they contain a discrete amount of elements (an integer).

Comment: For example $\left\{n \mod 3\right\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ or  $\left\{n \mod 3\right\}_{n\to\infty}$

Comment: @Elementary You keep using infinities as indices. It does not make sense formally. Note how in my answer the indices are always finite, even when using an infinite limit. An infinite set would be notated $\{n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, although the example you tried to give only has three elements, $\{0, 1, 2\}$.

Comment: Yes, I know I have a hard time understanding. I fixed the question. $n$ is equal to lenth of sequence which is consist of $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$. Then I include $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Elementary Sorry, that's simply not an operation. $n \to \infty$ is not a *thing* and I don't know what you mean when you include it. Both $A_\infty$ and $A_{n\to\infty}$ are not standard notation so no one knows what *exactly* you mean.

Comment: Thank you for answer.